# $n=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, How many subsets of cardinality $k$ containing element 1 are in $n$?

Tags: combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combinatorics: Number of subsets with cardinality k with 1 element.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254197/combinatorics-number-of-subsets-with-cardinality-k-with-1-element)

A set n has elements $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. How many subsets does it have of cardinality $k$ and that contains element $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: After you put $1$ in each possible set, you then have to fill in the remaining $k-1$ spaces from the other $n-1$ elements. How many ways can you do this?